# Add custom properties to an alert rule in Azure

Tags: azure, kql, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I have a Use Case i am working on.
An Alert is fired in Azure when some conditions are met:
Condition: Whenever the total task complete events is greater than 0
The alert rule has some basic information.
Subscription
Resource Type
Resource Group

There is a Custom properties section and i want to use this to enrich the alert rule.The information I am hoping to include is in a table called AzureDiagnostics. Field values,conditions i need as follows (i included some custom fields):
`OperationName=="TaskCompleteEvent" jobId_s id_s == "analyse" ElapsedTime=datetime_diff('second', executionInfo_endTime_t, executionInfo_startTime_t) ElapsedTime_in_Hours_Minutes_Seconds=ElapsedTime * 1s TimeGenerated`
Can someone guide me on the best way to include these as custom properties? Adds value to the alert instead of then going back into azure to find more information. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score -1):

I don't really have enough information to go on to properly answer this however, if you are referring to a default rule that you cannot edit, you can easily create an automation rule to autoclose the alert, you use custom KQL to reference the **SecurityAlert** table to enrich, such as

```
SecurityAlert | where DisplayName contains "previousRuleName"
```

or

If it is already custom KQL you can simply add, whether that's to the same table by removing the already specified column or otherwise, by using the join ( operator